# Creating listbox items from a large string

Tags: c#

I have a large string that contains text:

```
"value 1

value 2

value 3

etc..." //over 100 values
```

I am trying to create a listbox with it's items based on the values in this string.

I used a try catch as I was getting an argument out of range exception which stopped the error but I can't see any items in the listbox :P

```
string value = "";

int currentIndexPos = 0;

foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m in System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(listStr, "\r\n?"))
{
    try
    {
        value = formatted.Substring(currentIndexPos, m.Index - 1); // -1 so the matched value isn't used.

        listBox1.Items.Add(value);

        currentIndexPos = m.Index + 1;
    }

    catch
    { 
        //argument out of range exception
        //Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the value of m.Index?

Comment: On the very first match would the index of m be 0?  Thus the m.Index - 1 would yield the argument out of range error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As many have said, just use String.Split. However, there's no need for a foreach loop or resorting to LINQ, just do this:

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(String.Split(...));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
var values = listStr.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach(string value in values)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(value);
}
```

Comment: ended up using a combination of 2 answers :P listBox1.Items.AddRange(formatted.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

Answer (score 1):

Since you are in essence doing a split why not use that function and ignore the index operations.

```
var lst = String.Split("\r".ToCharArray(),"listStr");
lst.select((x)=>listBox1.Items.Add(x));
```

Comment: When I try to add this I get: "The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: I tried adding that too :P Still get an error, I think it may String.Split, for some reason VS2010 doesnt recognise it... though it's just in System.String.Split :P But typing it won't auto fill in like everything else...